# MetaData on http request - servlets

Tags: java, http, servlets

I was wondering what kind of metadata is important to save on incoming `http` request.

Beside `headers`, `Cookies` and Session ID, is there more metadata that is important to log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering what kind of metadata is important to save on incoming HTTP request.

It depends on your needs, but you always can log the HTTP method, the URL and the headers (it includes `Cookie` and `Authorization` headers).

You also may want to log the IP address of the caller and the request date/time.